# Cufontext not hiding in IE after being replaced by cufon

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cufon

This is my site: http://travel.web2c.eu

it is a wordpress installation and the theme is using cufon fonts.
The problem is that in the main page (which is in Greek) the cufontext is not hiding when replaced by cufon. So when the page loads I see every title twice.
This happens only in the main page. Inner pages although they use the same template as the main page are displaying correctly.

The error is displayed when i enable some plugins such as WP UI, GT tabs, sociable, sexybookmarks etc. I tried to avoid plugins that cause the problem, but almost 80% of wp plugins are causing this so I decided to search for a solution.

I posted the error at the theme support page but still no answer.
This is the link: http://support.ait-themes.com/discussion/4172/display-error-in-ie9-probably-with-the-fonts
You can see two screenshots, the first one is with most pluginis disabled, and the second one has GT Tabs enabled (it's the current state of the site).

I would be grateful if anyone could help.
Thanks in advance.